# Let $m$ and $n$ be odd integers. Prove $ \sum_{i=1}^{m}i^n≡ 0 \pmod{m}$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, congruences

Let $m$ and $n$ be odd integers. Prove $ \sum_{i=1}^{m}i^n≡ 0 \pmod{m}$

Here's my attempt at an Induction Proof:

Let this
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{m}i^n≡ 0  \pmod{m} $$ 
be correct for some $m$. Now let's prove that's correct also for $m+1$:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{m+1}i^{n} = i^1+\dots+i^m+i^{m+1} ≡ 0  \pmod{m} $$ 
and then this $i^1+\dots+i^m$ is divisible by $m$ because the first part of induction.

What next? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Well you didn't prove it for the base case. And also you're assuming it's true for $n$ odd, but in the induction step, $n+1$ is not odd

Comment: i dont know how to prove this i am stuck here @Brenton

Comment: The first thing to do is to phrase the question correctly, otherwise your chance of getting good help is quite low.  What you've written is not correct, since $1^2 + 2^2 = 5 \not\equiv 0\pmod{2}$.  At least we should assume that $n$ is odd, in which case it is obvious that direct induction on $n$ will not work.

Comment: It's also not clear doing an induction proof why you're inducting on $n$ instead of $m$

Comment: But the assignment says that both are odd @Slade

Comment: It might.  But your _question_ doesn't, and if you expect anyone to understand your question, you should include all of the information from the assignment.  And you should include the information that it _is_ an assignment, so that we understand the context in which you encountered this problem.

Comment: Indeed, $m$ odd is also a necessary assumption, since $1^5 + 2^5 =33 \not\equiv 0\pmod{5}$.

Comment: Hint:   Pair $t^n$ and $(m-i)^n$.

Comment: ...okay, I just saw the title.  In general, critical information should be put into the body of the question.

Comment: is this better? @Brenton

Comment: I think that it goes $3^1+3^2+++3^m$ @Slade

Comment: The induction step as well needs to be $\pmod{m+1}$ if you're inducting on $m$

Comment: @math16666666666 Only if you're asking about $\sum_{n=1}^m i^n$.  But the question says $\sum_{i=1}^m i^n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $m,n$ be odd integers, then we want to show $$\sum_{i=1}^{m}i^n \equiv 0  \pmod{m}.$$

---

Lets look at an example $$1^7 + 2^7 + 3^7 + 4^7 + 5^7 \equiv 0 \pmod 5.$$

Clearly we can throw away the last term: $$1^7 + 2^7 + 3^7 + 4^7 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$

Now notice that half the terms may be written as negatives $$1^7 + 2^7 + (-1 \cdot 2)^7 + (-1)^7 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$

and we can pull that sign out when we have an odd exponent $$1^7 + 2^7 - (2^7 + 1^7) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$ which is obviously true.

---

this inspires a proof: $$\sum_{i=1}^{m}i^n \equiv \sum_{i=1}^{m-1} i^n \equiv \left(\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)/2} i^n\right) + \left(\sum_{i=(m+1)/2}^{m-1} i^n\right)$$ $$\equiv \left(\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)/2} i^n\right) + \left(\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)/2} (m-i)^n\right)\equiv \left(\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)/2} i^n\right) - \left(\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)/2} i^n\right)\equiv 0 .$$

Answer (score -1):

$\begin{array}\\
i^n+(m-i)^n
&=i^n+\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}m^j(-1)^{n-j}i^{n-j}\\
&=i^n+(-1)^ni^n+\sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n}{j}m^j(-1)^{n-j}i^{n-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n}{j}m^j(-1)^{n-j}i^{n-j}
\qquad\text{since }n\text{ is odd}\\
&=m\sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n}{j}m^{j-1}(-1)^{n-j}i^{n-j}\\
&≡ 0  \pmod{m}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}i^n
=\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}(m-i)^n
$,
$2\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}i^n
≡ 0  \pmod{m}
$.

Since $m$ is odd,
this implies that
$\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}i^n
≡ 0  \pmod{m}
$.

(I know you can skip this
by pairing symmetric terms,
but,
what the heck.)

Note that the term
$m^n$ can be ignored.

Comment: Why the downvote?